# #define ALLOC(p,n) (p*)malloc(sizeof(p)*n))

Tags: c, compiler-errors, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to allocate some memory using MACROS. But I get this errors:

> error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
>
> error: expected statement before ‘)’ token

This is my code:

```
#define ALLOC(p,n) (p*)malloc(sizeof(p)*n)

int main(){
  char *ponteiro;
  ponteiro=ALLOC(5,ponteiro);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: count the brackets in your macro definition..

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
#define ALLOC(p,n) (p*)malloc(sizeof(p)*n)
```

to:

```
#define ALLOC(p,n) malloc(sizeof(*(p))*(n))
```

and in the `main()`  free the allocated memory before `return`

```
int main(){
    char *ponteiro;
    ponteiro = ALLOC(ponteiro,5);
    /* Do something */
    free(ponteiro);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#define ALLOC(p,n) malloc(sizeof(*(p))*   (n)    )` important to put **every** macro parameter in parenthesis, always! Imagine what happens if you use it with the very common expression: `ponteiro = ALLOC(ponteiro, 1+strlen(foo));`. Your macro would expand to: `malloc(sizeof(*(ponteiro))*1+strlen(foo))`, which is clearly a **BUG**.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 #define ALLOC(p,n) (p*)malloc(sizeof(p)*n))
```

to

```
 #define ALLOC(n,p) malloc( sizeof(*(p)) * (n) )
```

because

1. `return` of `malloc()` [need not to be casted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
2. `n` represents the number of elements, an `p` is the pointer, so the MACRO definition should change.
3. `sizeof(p)` is wrong, as the `p` is supposed to be the pointer variable name itself. You need to have `sizeof(*p)`.

That said,

- The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`
- You should `free()` the allocated memory after the usage is done.

Comment: Please add some parentheses.

Comment: Use this: `#define ALLOC(n, p) malloc(sizeof (*(p)) * (n))` to prevent weird behaviour.

Comment: Some stylistic guidelines advise against leaving out the parentheses around the operand to `sizeof`.

Comment: basically , i need to allocate some memory to any array using some MACRO (programation test). And the code that i wrote have some errors

Comment: @DavidFerreira **do not change your code in a way that makes the existing answer invalid.** It already earned me one downvote. :-)

Comment: ok, updates...two downvotes, now I'm really interested..... What is that obvious mistake which I (seems to be the only person) am missing  here...Anybody, help please?

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, it's not fine. Please include all the parentheses I wrote. For instance, if you write `ALLOC(a + b, p)`, your code generates `malloc(sizeof(*p) * a + b)` which is incorrect due to operator precedence.

Comment: @FUZxxl Yes, you're right. I was thinking of the pointer only, the size should also be taken care in this regard. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Another nitpick: It's both okay to not `free` memory before calling `exit` (why clean up the carpet when you're destroying the house?) and to not put `void` in the argument list of `main` (since C99, in a *definition* [not a declaration] of a function, an empty argument list denotes a function that takes no arguments)

Comment: @FUZxxl 1) agree, only if it's `main()` returning from other functions without both returning the allocated pointer and freeing will cause leak 2) see 5.1.2.2.1 of `C11` which says to use `(void)`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The standard gives an example of what the definition could look like. `int main() { ... }` is a definition with the exact same effect, this changed with C99.

Answer (score 0):

The macro needs some extra parentheses and you made a mistake: you must pass the type to the macro:

```
 ponteiro=ALLOC(char, 5);
```

Fix the macro this way:

```
 #define ALLOC(p,n)  ((p*)malloc(sizeof(p)*(n)))
```